# Checking himself for permissions for discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This bot used to work normally all of a suddent it does this

```
const perm = vc.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
```

The output is

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'PermissionsFor')
```

I do not know how to fix this issue so i am ready to be berated by people who are better than me

Comment: No beratement from me, if you just updated from v12 to v13, then permissionsFor was deprecated but to see how it will help in your instence can you please provide more code (It looks like you are checking the permissions that the bot has for a voice channel but want to confirm)

Comment: The problem isn't in the bit of code you provided. As you can see from the error `vc` is most likely `null` and so you should include the part where you defined `vc` because I guess that is the actual source of this error. Also in the first code it's `permissionsFor` but in the error it's `PermissionsFor` not sure if it's a typo or not